# How can I solve this strange MySQL locking behavior in a Python Thread?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, deadlock

I have a Python script with a handful of threads linked together by queues. One of the threads has a MySQLdb connection that is used in the init function of the thread, and in the main loop in the thread's main loop as well.

Now when the script runs, the MySQLdb connection works just fine in the init part of the thread. But when it is used in the thread's main loop, it deadlocks completely on the `self.cursor.execute(SQL)` line. Now things get even weirder when I hit Ctrl-C after the deadlock. The deadlock is then broken and the MySQLdb cursor gets its result and the thread continues just fine until the KeyboardInterupt is caught.

I have used the same code before many times, but this is the first time I have used MySQLdb in  it. I have never ever come across this behavior before, and I am at a loss trying to understand what is going on here. It's one thing if I would have some exception to refer to, but there is none. Also, I don't really understand why the `self.cursor.execute(SQL)` line actually returns the correct value after I hit Ctrl-C.

I am not at liberty to show the actual code, but believe me, it is completely straight forward without any frills. The thread's main loop is just a while loop with a Queue get function with a MySQLdb query straight after. It doesn't seem to be a SQL issue as I have tried with the simplest `SELECT 'hello'` query and it still leads to the same behavior.

What could be the reason for this behavior?

FWIW, I am using Python 2.7 and I get the same behavior on OS X / Ubuntu 11.10.

**EDIT:** I am starting to wonder whether it's something caused by the MySQL server setup. I just tried using another Python MySQL library (pymysql), and it gives the same behavior.

**EDIT2:** I just restarted the MySQL server with the slow log queries thing. Strangely enough I can see the other queries but the query that blocks doesn't show up.

**EDIT3: [solved sort of]** I found [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577334-how-to-debug-deadlocked-multi-threaded-programs/) recipe detailing how to see what the threads are up to. After a bit of debugging it became obvious that the culprit was imports within the MySQLdb module. I then simply commented out rows 83-95 in MySQLdb/cursors.py and it suddenly worked ok. I don't think those lines are that important anyway as they only seem to render some warnings and I am sure of the quality of these particular queries I am running.

If someone actually knows a more robust way around the issue I'd love to hear it though.

Comment: what did you comment out?

Comment: I fixed this issue by lowering the insert amount of my `executemany()` statements - I changed it from `5000` inserts to `1000` and deadlock stopped - This just makes the transactions quicker between connections

Answer (score 1):

May be you're sharing the connection between threads. MySQLdb [documents](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) recommends

> Don't share connections between
>   threads. It's really not worth your effort or mine, and in the end,
>   will probably hurt performance, since the MySQL server runs a separate
>   thread for each connection. You can certainly do things like cache
>   connections in a pool, and give those connections to one thread at a
>   time. If you let two threads use a connection simultaneously, the
>   MySQL client library will probably upchuck and die. You have been
>   warned.

Comment: Yea I read that part too. But am I really sharing connections between threads though? I am technically just using it in a single thread. Or am I misunderstanding something here?